# How customize fields in the Django admin interface

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a model in my Django project with a member which is a char field.  Basically data in this field will be entered as comma-separated values.

Without a long-winded explanation of what the overall goal of this is, basically rather than having the admin interface use a simple text field, I'd rather have have some custom HTML for the form so I can just use checkboxes and assemble the values of the checked boxes into a CSV string myself once the form is submitted.

Most of the django customization I was able to find on Google didn't answer my particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly I think you want to search for writing custom widgets. Perhaps start here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/